# when this.props is passed to the child component, it becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React project component structure is very simple: App >> SearchResults >> TrackList.
To test, I output the value of the data in each component.
In the **App.js** file, I used this.state to define an array of objects called *searchResults*.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [
        {
          name: 'name-1',
          artist: 'artist-1',
          alblum: 'alblum-1',
          id: 101
        },
        {
          name: 'name-2',
          artist: 'artist-2',
          alblum: 'alblum-2',
          id: 202
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    console.log('Here is App.js', this.state.searchResults);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
            <Playlist />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In the **SearchResults.js** file, I used tracks={this.props.searchResults} to pass the data to the child component.

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Here is SearchResults.js', this.props searchResults);
    return (
      <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

In the **TrackList.js** file, I output the data from parent component.

```
class TrackList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log('Here is TrackList.js', this.props.tracks);
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id} track={track} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList
```

But, strange things happen, the console prints the data twice, showing the normal values the first time, and undefined the second time.
Because of this, I cannot use the.map() function for this data.
Why did this happen, and how to fix it?

**console screenshot is here: [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77q2D.png)**

Comment: By any chance, is the trackList component used somewhere else too??

Comment: It's pretty tough to tell from your code what's going on. Can you post a codesandbox (or similar) link? From what I can tell, you shouldn't be having issues.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri My god!!! You're a genius. You know how long I've been testing this question, four hours!!! I did use <TrackList /> in another component and totally forgot about it

Comment: @Yanze, no issues glad to have helped